# How to change the back of video in vonage

Tags: javascript, css, vonage

Members,

I am using Vonage API for video calling.

I want to change the video background, Can anyone guide me on this.!

Looking forward to hearing from you!!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The Vonage Video APIs does not currently support this out of the box - you will need to integrate a 3rd party library, dependent on what platform and programming language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Background replacement and Insertable Streams are on the roadmap in early 2022, but as for now the only thing available to alter the background, using only the Vonage Video API, is the recently released (still in beta) Background Blur method. This is applied to the Publisher via the method [applyVideoFilter](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#applyVideoFilter).

Example:

```js
// Start the BG Blur before publishing
OT.initPublisher(someContainer, {
   videoFilter: {
      type: 'backgroundBlur',
   },
})

// Start the BG Blur after publishing
await publisher.applyVideoFilter({
   type: 'backgroundBlur',
   blurStrength: 'low',
})

// Stopping the BG Blur after publishing
await publisher.clearVideoFilter();
```

In the April 2022 announcement:
Added support for filtering video for the publisher. This is a beta feature. Currently, only a background blur filter can be applied. See the `videoFilter` property of the `option` parameter you pass into [OT.initPublisher()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/release-notes.html#:%7E:text=you%20pass%20into-,OT.initPublisher(),-method.%20Also%2C%20see) method. Also, see the docs for the [Publisher.applyVideoFilter()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#applyVideoFilter), [Publisher.getVideoFilter()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/release-notes.html#:%7E:text=Publisher.getVideoFilter()), and [Publisher.clearVideoFilter()](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#clearVideoFilter) methods.

You can read more in the [Vonage Developer Docs](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#:%7E:text=applyVideoFilter(videoFilter)).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this library to add background blur and replacement https://npm.io/package/@vonage/video-effects

Comment: I think the code is in node JS, Am using the JS and HTML.
Can you please help me on that

Comment: Please go through the link again. You need to install the package using node, but after that you can use the JavaScript files in your web app